# Split string to dict with good performance

Tags: python, string, split, cython

I search best method for split long string look like `b'a: 1\nb: 2\n ...'` - about 50-70 keys.

Length of string is 8-10K bytes.
So, I have about 1K strings per second.

By best method looks like:

```
dict(x.split(b": ") for x in bytes(headers).split(b'\n'))
```

Maybe cython gives good result?

Comment: `x.split(b": ", 1)` might save a little time

Comment: @DavidW Thanks! On set data 789MB -0.1 second.

Comment: I search sample with quoting/unquoting. https://github.com/aio-libs/yarl/blob/master/yarl/_quoting_c.pyx . Its about 2x faster. I will change the method for the split event.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like this which will only use `itertools` to save memory on long strings and:

```py
    from itertools import pairwise
        
    def string_to_dict(str_value):
        #l is a list of indices of each '\n' inside the string ​
       ​l = []
       ​i = 0
       ​while i<len(str_value):
           ​if str_value[i] == b'\n':l.append(i)
           ​i+=1
       ​#pairwise(l) will give us a list of 2-tuple indices to get each
       # substring in the format 'key:value'
       #str_value[x[0]+1:x[1]].split(b': ') will give us (key, value) tuple
       #to dynamically create the global dict
       result_dict = dict(str_value[x[0]+1:x[1]].split(b': ') for x in pairwise(l))
       return result_dict
```

or more efficient again, the following will save memory at the price of the compute

```py
    def string_to_dict(str_value):
        w = (i for i in range(len(str_value)) if str_value[i]==b'\n')
        result_dict = dict(str_value[x[0]+1:x[1]].split(b': ') for x in pairwise(w))
        return result_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the input is well-formed, we could replace the `:`  delimiter with the same delimiter (`\n`), and split both at once, then slice for keys/values.

The code looks something like:

```py
def fast_split(data):
    items = bytes(data).replace(b": ", b"\n").split(b"\n")
    return dict(zip(items[::2], items[1::2]))
```

On my machine, its about 3x faster-

```py
from timeit import timeit

size = 100000
test_str = b"\n".join([b"a: 1"] * size)


def slow_split(data):
    return dict(x.split(b": ") for x in bytes(data).split(b'\n'))

def fast_split(data):
    items = bytes(data).replace(b": ", b"\n").split(b"\n")
    return dict(zip(items[::2], items[1::2]))

print(fast_split(test_str) == slow_split(test_str))

print(timeit("slow_split(test_str)", number=100, setup="from __main__ import slow_split, test_str"))
print(timeit("fast_split(test_str)", number=100, setup="from __main__ import fast_split, test_str"))
```

```
True
1.373571052972693
0.4970768200000748
```

Comment: Thanks. On my test data: slow 0:00:04.905767 and fast 0:00:04.944033

Comment: @AlexeyPanevin Could you share some test data for me to optimize against? Whether that be via pastebin, or a small python snippet to generate it programmatically. I think I know why this is currently so much faster- my test data has only one key (repeated), so the cost of the dict creation itself is diminished

Comment: Test data is "!adwefwersg: cdef void get_a_c_string(char** c_string_ptr, Py_ssize_t *length)" * 10000000. Prod data is event from ESL https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_event_socket. So, function parse event data.

Answer (score 0):

Converting your `:` to a `\n` (and removing spaces) would allow you to use only one split operation.  The dictionary can be created by pairing every two values returned by splitting on '\n'.

```
sep = bytes.maketrans(b':',b'\n')

d = dict(zip(*[iter(s.translate(sep,b' ').split(b'\n'))]*2))
```

Assuming you setup `sep` only once, this is roughly 2 times faster (on 10,000 distinct dictionary keys).